# Trouble making a square address form on react-square-web-payments-sdk with nextjs13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, square

I am trying to collect the user address, I expected there to be an address form in the package.

Should I make my own form, or is there a form that is part of the package?

I also see I am supposed to use `payments.verifybuyer()`. I don't know where to get the payments variable from. The docs weren't super clear.

```
<PaymentForm
    createPaymentRequest={() => ({
        countryCode: "US",
        currencyCode: "USD",
        total: {
            amount: "1.00",
            label: "Total",
        },
    })}
    applicationId="sandbox-sq0idb-Hjbfh1xVL93-HxQiP4csTg"
    cardTokenizeResponseReceived={async (token, verifiedBuyer) => {
        const response = await fetch("/api/pay", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                sourceId: token.token,
            }),
        });
        console.log(await response.json());
    }}
    createVerificationDetails={() => ({
        amount: '1.00',
        billingContact: {
            addressLines: ['123 Main Street', 'Apartment 1'],
            familyName: 'Doe',
            givenName: 'John',
            countryCode: 'GB',
            city: 'London',
        },
        currencyCode: 'GBP',
        intent: 'CHARGE',
    })}
    locationId='LDMMSQDX5M7ZP'
>
    <CreditCard />
    <GooglePay />
</PaymentForm>
```